# What is the legality of atheist marriage among consanguineous couples in India?

Tags: india, marriage

I am preparing an academic report on laws regarding incest in India. Hinduism law and both major schools under Islamic law [consider sibling marriage void](https://blog.ipleaders.in/incest-in-india/#Void_marriage_in_Hindu_laws). A [Special Marriage Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Marriage_Act,_1954) was introduced to govern the marriage among atheists. However I could not find any information regarding consanguineous couples.

Answer (score 2):

See [footnote 9](https://www.webcitation.org/5syrz9P0c) from your Wikipedia link to the Special Marriage Act:

> **Necessary Conditions For A Marriage**
>
> The following conditions are necessary :
>
> ...
>
> 6. That the parties are not within the degrees of prohibited relationship. However where a custom governing at least one of the
>    parties permits a marriage between them, such marriage may be
>    solemnized nonwithstanding that they are within the degrees of
>    prohibited relationship as follows:
>
> **degrees of prohibited relationship**
>
> A man and any of the person mentioned in part I of the first schedule
> and a woman and any of the person mentioned in Part II of the said
> schedule are with in the degrees of prohibited relationship.
>
> Relationship includes
>
> (a) relationship by half or uterine blood as well as by fool [sic] blood;
>
> (b) illegitimate blood relationship as well as legitimate;
>
> (c) relationship by adoption as well as by blood; and all terms of
> relationship in this Act shell be construed accordingly.
>
> ''Full blood'' and ''half blood''- Two person are said to be related
> to each other by full blood when they are descended from the common
> ancestor but by different wives.
>
> ''Uterine blood''- Two persons are said to be related to each other by
> uterine blood when they are descended from a common ancestress but by
> different husbands.
>
> ''Ancester'' includes the father and ''ancestress'' the mother.

Parts 1 and 2 of the First Schedule provide a comprehensive list of the prohibited relationships but are too voluminous to quote here.

Comment: Is "fool blood" a typo for "full blood", perhaps an error in the source?

Comment: @DavidSiegel It must be a typo. lol

Comment: Or perhaps it refers to one who marries unwisely, lol. Seriously if it seems to be an error in the source, it can be indicated by including "[sic]" to call attention to it, and indicate that it is not your error.

Comment: I'm ahead of you. Already done.